# Any rails developer using Windows as a dev system for real world apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I was considering migrating from asp.net MVC 3 to Rails, however, when I read that Rails (or Ruby for that matter) dev support on Windows was shacky at best, I began to back-off from this idea. At this point it seems that unless you stick to a LAMP type stack for rails (in dev and production mode), you will have difficulty getting support if you are based on windows.

Is there anybody here who has created a complex rails web app on Windows?

Comment: this will be a pretty subjective answer, so i'll just post in the comments..."We are creating a huuuge app that's supposed to run on any OS. I tell you BACK AWAY! there are so many compatibility problems, gem problems, FORKING, processes whatever etc. if your app is using any of those or more complex stuff, research on it first but i suggest you rather stick with unix machines

Comment: LAMP has nothing to do with Rails. Rails development is easiest (for me) on a Unix-like operating system simply because the CLI is meant to be used, where in Windows the CLI is pretty much an after-thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best you can do as developer is keep your developer's environment closer to real production base. It saves a lot if time on debugging unexpected behaviour and fixing strange bugs. If you don't be able to use *nix, try to setup Virtual Machine with ports forwarding of 22 and 3000 ports